# Optimizing performance when supporting multiple devices

Tags: java, android, optimization, runnable

I have an app that implements a runnable.  Said runnable runs every 2.5 seconds.  Inside of the runnable I made a switch that lays out the instructions for the runnable at different densities (the runnable moves an image across the screen, and for xhdpi devices they need to move a different parameters than mdpi devices, obviously).  My question is, would it be more efficient to list different runnables for each resolution instead.  Is the runnable going through each case for densities before running?  It seems like that would eat up a lot of resource.  Thanks for any insight.  Some code is posted below:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new     
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params2 = new 
LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params3 = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
            switch(metrics.densityDpi){
                 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                     params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*704 + 1);
                     params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*1334 + 1);
                     params2.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*704 + 1);
                     params2.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*1334 + 1);
                     params3.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*704 + 1);
                     params3.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*1334 + 1);
                     MapView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/ldpimap.html");
                        break;
                 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                     params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*1299 + 1);
                     params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*2419 + 1);
                     params2.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*1299 + 1);
                     params2.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*2419 + 1);
                     params3.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*1299 + 1);
                     params3.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*2419 + 1);
                     MapView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/mdpimap.html");
                             break;
                 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                     params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*3039 + 1);
                     params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*5559 + 1);
                     params2.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*3039 + 1);
                     params2.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*5559 + 1);
                     params3.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*3039 + 1);
                     params3.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*5559 + 1);
                     MapView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hdpimap.html");
                             break;
                 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH:
                     params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*5489 + 1);
                     params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*9969 + 1);
                     params2.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*5489 + 1);
                     params2.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*9969 + 1);
                     params3.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*5489 + 1);
                     params3.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*9969 + 1);
                     MapView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xhdpimap.html");
                            break;
                 case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XXHIGH:
                     params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*8649 + 1);
                     params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*14749 + 1);
                     params2.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*8649 + 1);
                     params2.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*14749 + 1);
                     params3.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*8649 + 1);
                     params3.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*14749 + 1);
                     MapView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/xxhdpimap.html");
            }

            fImage.setLayoutParams(params);
            fImage2.setLayoutParams(params2);
            fImage3.setLayoutParams(params3);

            handler.postDelayed(this, 2350);

                }
    };
    r.run();
```

Comment: 1.  Don't optimise until you need to.  2.  Why don't you just step through with the debugger to see which path is taken?  3.  Why don't you just measure the different approaches?

Comment: I agree with Simon.  Try using android's traceview tool to measure the performance between your different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

> would it be more efficient to list different runnables for each resolution instead.

There's a negligible difference. In theory switch/if inside of a loop is slower. As the resolution never changes it costs maybe 1 cycle per iteration. The loop takes some thousand cycles at least, so forget it.

> Is the runnable going through each case for densities before running?

No, why?

More important is clean code. You could replace the switch by using a table.

Comment: I'm a bit new to developing for android.  What exactly are you referencing when you mention using a table instead of a switch?  Will cleaning up such a small amount of code yield any better performance?  Because my phone has begun to lag, not severely, but noticeably upon implementing this switch.

Comment: The table won't make it faster. In your switch I can't see anything problematic. Are you it's because of it? Try to comment out the branches you don't need in your experiment, try also comment out the switch itself, but I strongly doubt, anything changes.